# How to remove suggestions from keyboard with "@"?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I'm having an EditText where I set the `inputType="textEmailAddress|textVisiblePassword"`. But the keyboard still shows suggestion. I want to remove the suggestions and keyboard should show "@".

Comment: have you tried `inputType="textEmailAddress|textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions`?

Comment: You have no way of *forcing* an input method editor to have any particular key, such as `@`. You have no way of forcing an `input` method editor to not show suggestions. `inputType` and related attributes on an `EditText` are hints, not demands. The behavior of an input method editor is up to its developers. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed input method editors across the ~10,000 Android device models and ~2 billion Android devices.

Comment: @ADM yeah. not working

Comment: tried everything

Comment: What do you mean? "suggestion"